# Limitations of variable function name `##` syntax

Tags: macros, syntax, portability, c-preprocessor

Occasionally, C/C++ syntax blows my mind and today is one of those days. I stumbled across some code that uses macros with `##` to generate unique and individual accessor methods to specific hardware registers (shown below).

**Question:** What limitations or concerns exist with the `##` syntax?

```
static uint8_t write(uint16_t _addr, uint8_t _data);  // Implemented elsewhere
static uint8_t read(uint16_t addr);                   // Implemented elsewhere

#define __GP_REGISTER8(name, address)             \
  static inline void write##name(uint8_t _data) { \
    write(address, _data);                        \
  }                                               \
  static inline uint8_t read##name() {            \
    return read(address);                         \
  }

__GP_REGISTER8 (A, 0x0000);    // Register A
__GP_REGISTER8 (B, 0x0001);    // Register B
__GP_REGISTER8 (C, 0x0002);    // Register C

#undef __GP_REGISTER8
```

After implementing the preceding macros, you now have the ability to make the following calls:

```
writeA(0xA5);
writeB(0x5A);
uint8_t c_value = readC();
```

How does `##` work exactly (i.e. only in macros, etc.)? Also, do people not use this because it doesn't really offer any advantage and it is more work, or are there other side-effects / drawbacks to using this technique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (almost) not about C++ syntax but about the C preprocessor language.  The feature is called *token pasting* or *concatenation*.  From the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation):

> The `##` preprocessing operator performs token pasting.  When a macro is expanded, the two tokens on either side of each `##` operator are combined into a single token, which then replaces the `##` and the two original tokens in the macro expansion.

So in your (simplified) example,

```cpp
__GP_REGISTER8(A, 0x0000)
```

expands (by string substitution) to

```
static inline void write ## A(uint8_t _data) { write(0x0000, _data); }
```

Then, the preprocessor replaces the `write ## A` triple with `writeA` as you have observed it.

> What limitations or concerns exist with the `##` syntax?

It is dirty macro trickery that might confuse people like it did you.  The limitations are quite clear: You can perform token pasting – nothing less and nothing more.  Let me re-emphasize that all this takes place *before* the C or C++ compiler sees the code.  Therefore, if you “call” such a macro with nonsense arguments, the preprocessor will still expand it happily and only then the compiler will see garbage and output an error message of little help.  That said, if the macro is used inside a header file to clean up repetitive declarations, it is probably fine.

Tricks like these have lost much of their importance with the growing power of C++ template metaprogramming.  One could reasonably argue that the functionality that was implemented with the macros you have posted could have been implemented equally well using templated functions like in

```cpp
enum class Registers { A = 0x0000, B = 0x0001, C = 0x0002; };

template<Registers R>
void
write(uint16_t data)
{
    write(static_cast<int>(R), data);
}
```

and then used as

```cpp
write<Registers::A>(0xA5);
```